# Convert raw phone numbers into clickable links

Tags: php, html

I have a directory website which has tons of phone numbers, all in the same format.
I'd like to turn them into clickable links especially for mobile.

I simply want to add this format to the numbers:

```
<a href="tel:555-555-5555">555-555-5555</a>
```

The issue is I have tons of pages and the numbers are getting pulled in using this code:

```
$html[] = 'Phone: '.$row['phone'].' <br/>';
```

That results in a layout like this:

*Phone: (770)431-9787*

Is there anything I can do to that line of code to turn it into a hyperlink? Something like this maybe? I get errors, but is anything like that possible?

```
$html[] = 'Phone: '.$row<a href="tel:['phone']">['phone']</a>.' <br/>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP's double-quotes string interpolation:

```
$html[] = "Phone: <a href='tel:{$row['phone']}'>{$row['phone']}</a><br/>";
```

In your example, you have the `a` tag outside the string, which is unrecognizable by PHP.